# Number of elements of the same norm in a quadratic ring

Tags: nt.number-theory

Consider the ring $Z(\sqrt D)$ where $D$ is a negative integer.
Let $N$ be a positive integer.  I wonder if there is a formula/estimate
for the number of elements of norm exactly $N$ ?

Comment: The answer strongly depends on the factorization of $N$; are you looking for an estimate that doesn't depend on this information? 

Comment: Put $n=-D$.  Then you are looking for the number of solutions to $x^2+ny^2=N$, i.e., the number of representations $r_Q(N)$ of $N$ by the binary quadratic form $Q:x^2+ny^2$.  I suggest you look at the literature on this.

Comment: The function is clearly going to be "badly behaved" in the following (perhaps weak) sense: there will be huge values of $N$ for which the number of elements of norm $N$ will be as big as $log(N)$ (for example let $N=p^M$ for $p$ a prime of the form $x^2-Dy^2$) but for which there will be no elements at all of norm $N+1$ (for silly congruence reasons).

Comment: I am looking for a upper bound that may depend on both $D$ and $N$. 
What is the strongest upper bound one can get here ? (We assume both $D$ and $N$ are large.) 

Comment: Try the Gaussian integers ($D=-1.$) Then there is a simple formula based on the factorization of $N.$ See how you like that result.